# Executing Scala via TextMate

Tags: scala, textmate

I am going through the Scala book i bought and am trying to get TextMate to cooperate

[image]

I got the point where:

1. Fails
2. Works
3. Fails (understandably why) main is missing
4. What is it?
5. What is it?
6. What is it?

**What the difference between :**

- Run Script
- Run as script

**What are options 4,5,6?**

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why it gives you two run script options, but scala REPL is an interactive scala console. You can execute any scala statements on the fly with it. Option 4 will just start a console, option 5 I suppose with preload everything you have in your file, so you don't have to import everything yourself. 6 will start a console and let you execute whatever you selected.

Here's more about REPL: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/2097